# Occasionally Messages posted to the kafka went missing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Hi I am having a custom framework, which exposes API to publish as well as consume. I support a lot of topics for a user to post to and consume. This seems to work fine except that occasionally, after I publish the message to the topic, my consumer does not get any message.  It is weird because kafka is up and running fine. Other messages to other topics before and after this missed messages work fine. Messages to the same topic is also fed to the consumer after this incident.

If it helps, I have only one partition per topic. When I open the KafaServerLog/data directory and search for the specific topic, in my development environment, I see entries everytime, I publish and consume. However the issue where this occurs( in a client place) the log files are empty. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producer api gives you a callback which you can use to trace what is the occasional problem in producer. A sample code will look something like this:

```
try (Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerProps)) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("My-topic", "message payload"), new Callback() {
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception ex) {
            if (ex != null) {
                LOGGER.warn(String.format("Failed to produce record. Got Exception: %s", ex));
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Sent record successfully");
            }             
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bitswazsky. This would help me to prevent this issue, if any messages was not posted ( and i can retry). However is there a way to debug a running system, where such a message goes missing ( to say what went wrong)? I am unable to find any previous such occurrence reported in kafka. I understand that this can happen when the minimum quorum is not reached with some of the nodes being down. IN my case, it went missing randomly and messages before and after worked fine

Comment: You may want to check the contents of server.log and/or zookeeper logs. Sometimes if re-balancing is taking too long, things might go messy, although it shouldn't drop messages.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see that message available in Kafka topic, but not delivered to consumer?

It's difficult to debug or recreate your scenario but you can force ACKS to 'all' for the kafka producer. And also for verification, save the RecordMetadata of each message being sent by producer. It will help confirm that kafka did commit the message.

Not sure about the log files though.